# LaTeX3: elegant way to forward arguments (tokens, star, embelishments) to another command

Tags: macros, latex3, xparse

I struggle to define elegantly a LaTeX3 command and forward its arguments (notably stars, tokens, embellishments) to another command. I guess I might be able to make it work using `\expandonce` or alike, but I guess there is a better solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{st't-t.e_O{}m}{%
  I am a command called \IfBooleanT{#1}{with a star, }\IfBooleanT{#2}{with a prime, }\IfBooleanT{#3}{with a dash, }\IfBooleanT{#4}{with a dot, }\IfNoValueTF{#5}{}{with an underscore (#5), } with the optional argument ``#6'' and with the mandatory argument ``#7''.
}

%% This fails:
% \NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommand}{st't-t.e_O{}m}{%
%   \mycommand\IfBooleanT{#1}{*}\IfBooleanT{#2}{'}\IfBooleanT{#3}{.}\IfBooleanT{#4}{_{#4}}[foo#5]{#6}%
% }

%% This fails:
% \NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommand}{st't-t.e_O{}m}{%
%   \mycommand#1#2#3#4[foo#5]{#6}%
% }

\begin{document}
\mycommand'_{below text}[I am optional]{yes}

How to define a new command so that mynewcommand behave like mycommand except that it prepends a string like "foo" in front of the optional argument?

% \mynewcommand*'-._{below text}[I am optional]{yes}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are `\mycommand` and `\mynewcommand` ensured to share the same argument specification?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ sometimes yes (so if you have a solution for this case I am interested), but from time to time I will be interested by a more generic solution were the arguments might differ (e.g.\ one argument is removed, or computed differently).

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand if you told us in which context you plan to use this.

Comment: That's not the idea around `\NewDocumentCommand`. You just “normalize” the arguments and forward to other commands as “m” ones.

Comment: @egreg Agreed, and this will make the process slower (even if that hardly matters on modern hardware). But I provided an answer as requested nonetheless.

Comment: Well in my case I wanted to override existing commands provided by libraries. And `\NewDocumentCommand` is quite nice to use, so why would I want to use it simply as a wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? I think you must have overlooked argument `#3` (the argument `s-`) in `\mynewcommand`, so I took the liberty of adding it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{st't-t.e_O{}m}{%
  I am a command called \IfBooleanT{#1}{with a star, }\IfBooleanT{#2}{with a prime, }\IfBooleanT{#3}{with a dash, }\IfBooleanT{#4}{with a dot, }\IfValueT{#5}{with an underscore (#5), } with the optional argument ``#6'' and with the mandatory argument ``#7''.
}

% This works:
 \NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommand}{st't-t.e_O{}m}{%
   \expandafter\mycommand\expanded{\IfBooleanT{#1}{*}\IfBooleanT{#2}{'}\IfBooleanT{#3}{-}\IfBooleanT{#4}{.}\IfValueT{#5}{\unexpanded{_{#5}}}\unexpanded{[foo#6]{#7}}}%
 }

%% This fails:
% \NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommand}{st't-t.e_O{}m}{%
%   \mycommand#1#2#3#4[foo#5]{#6}%
% }

\begin{document}
\mycommand'_{below text}[I am optional]{yes}

How to define a new command so that mynewcommand behave like mycommand except that it prepends a string like "foo" in front of the optional argument?

\mynewcommand*'-._{below text}[I am optional]{yes}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\ExpandArgs{e}` instead of `\expandafter` (also removing `\expanded`).

Comment: @egreg I remember reading about `\ExpandArgs`, but I cannot recall where it is documented. Anyway, `\ExpandArgs{e}\mycommand{...}` doesn’t work. How is the syntax again? Feel free to update the answer.

Comment: @egreg Could you provide an example? `{e}` is not documented in https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/usrguide3.pdf, and I tried multiple variations without much success.

Comment: @Gaussler Thanks for your answer. I wish a solution exists without playing with expansion order, but I guess we don't have so much choice. Thanks! (btw, thanks for making me discover `\unexpanded`)

Comment: @Gaussler `\ExpandArgs` is documented in ["The LaTeX 2ε Sources, 2022-11-01 Patch level 1", File e: ltexpl.dtx Date: 2022/02/28 Version v1.3, page 80](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#page.80). || Commands defined in terms of `\NewDocumentCommand` are expansion-protected. Thus `\mycommand` of your example is expansion-protected - instead of `\expandafter\mycommand\expanded{...}` you can do `\expanded{\mycommand...}`.

Comment: @Gaussler Probably you read about `\ExpandArgs` in [LaTeX News
Issue 35, June 2022, CamelCase commands for changing arguments to csnames](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews35.pdf#page.3)?

Comment: @tobiasBora `\ExpandArgs` in a first step grabs two arguments. The 1st argument holds a list of expl3-argument specifiers, the 2nd holds a control sequence token which processes arguments. In the second step `\ExpandArgs` grabs and pre-processes arguments according to the list of expl3-argument specifiers in its 1st argument and places them as arguments behind the control sequence token which processes arguments and which came as its 2nd argument. So it's a wrapper for choosing one of expl3's `\exp_args:N...`-functions which also grabs the 1st `N`-type-argument. ...

Comment: @tobiasBora ...   expl3-argument-specifiers are documented in [interface3.pdf / The LaTeX3 Interfaces, Released 2023-02-22, 1.1 Naming functions and variables, page 3](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page.3).

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks for the reference. Regarding the alternative solution (which egreg also already demonstrated), I understand why it works, but fail to see what it improves other than saving a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 5):

Don't. It's not what `\NewDocumentCommand` is for.

Anyway, first fix the arguments in `\mynewcommand`: your list is off.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{st't-t.e_O{}m}{%
  I am a command called
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{with a star, }%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{with a prime, }%
  \IfBooleanT{#3}{with a dash, }%
  \IfBooleanT{#4}{with a dot, }%
  \IfValueT{#5}{with an underscore (#5), }
  with the optional argument ``#6'' and with the mandatory argument ``#7''.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mynewcommand}{st't-t.e{_}O{}m}{%
  \expanded{%
    \mycommand
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{'}%
    \IfBooleanT{#3}{-}%
    \IfBooleanT{#4}{.}
    \IfValueT{#5}{_{\unexpanded{#5}}}%
    [foo\unexpanded{#6}]%
    {\unexpanded{#7}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\mycommand'_{below text}[I am optional]{yes}

How to define a new command so that mynewcommand behave like mycommand except that it prepends a string like "foo" in front of the optional argument?

\mynewcommand*'-._{below text}[I am optional]{yes}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not completely unheard of to make `_` an active character, which was why I chose to wrap it in `\unexpanded` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused: why `\expanded` does not try to expand the `\mycommand` before the arguments are ready to be parsed?

Comment: @tobiasBora Because `\mycommand` has been defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, so it’s not expanded in `\edef` or `\expanded`.